# Scalar vs Vector signal Quantization

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, quantization

I am studying about scalar vs vector quantization, and I have an assignment to implement (in MATLAB) a scalar quantizer , using the Lloyd-Max algorithm, and a vector quantizer via k-means clustering.

The **vector** quantizer works in the R<sup>2</sup> vector space, so its input is a tuple of samples (input vector) and its output is also a two dimensional vector, corresponding to the centroid vector of the quantization region.

I am told that in order for the comparisons between the two quantizers to be accurate, I need to keep the *number of bits per sample*, **constant**. For example, in a **n-bit scalar** quantizer, there are 2<sup>n</sup> quantization regions, in one of which, a sample will get quantized into.

The equivalent **vector** quantizer, will have **2n** bits per input tuple, so that each sample is still represented by **n** bits.
So, with that logic, I think that the **vector** quantizer should have 2<sup>2n</sup> quantization/Voronoi regions.

I have to quantize an equal number of samples from a Gaussian source (source **A**), and from an AR(5) Random process (source **B**). From what I've studied, I think that the **scalar** quantizer is expected to perform a better quantization of source **A** (in the MSE-sense) and the **vector** quantizer should perform better in the AR process (source **B**), where the samples are correlated with each other.

However, when I quantize both of the forementioned sources, and compute the MSE between the original and the quantized signal, the vector quantizer gives a smaller MSE for both sources. So the vector quantizer, is more efficient (in the MSE-sense) for both the sources, which I think is wrong, as it should be more efficient only for the Autoregressive Random process and not for the Gaussian source, as well.

(I calculate the MSE as :`mse(input_signal - quantized_signal)`, so there's nothing wrong there.)

So my questions are:

1. Should (theoretically) the vector quantizer be more efficient in quantizing both the sources or only in the case of the AR process?
2. The **vector** quantizer equivalent of a **n-bit scalar** quantizer, should have **2n** or **2<sup>2n</sup>** quantization/Voronoi regions (second argument/cluster number of kmeans() ).

If needed I will post the MATLAB code, as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, as I am stuck on this for some days.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Did you use the same input signal for learning the quantization regions *and* testing the quantizer?

Answer (score 0):

K-Means is very similar to Lloyd Max algorithm.
Since you give it `x2` more bits there is no wonders it performs better.